# WebCenter Installation

Tags: installation, webcenter

Typically, how long should it take to install the Oracle WebCenter Suit?

We have a team of 3 developers trying to install WCS, however, it seems to be taking a little too long.

Comment: This is a broad question. Are you installing WebCenter Content Server, Sites, or Portal? What version? What OS? What DB? What steps have you completed? Where does it seem to be taking "too long"? Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It really hard to say without any environment info like db version, cluster, network, load balancing etc...

Normally, for a local development installation, with correct database and os version, and a little bit luck, bringing up a standalone webcenter stack should be around 1-3 days.

If your developers are really stuck with the installation.  I would suggest to get a Oracle pre-built VM for a good start without holding the enviroment

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#wcp
Oracle WebCenter Portal VM

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, but assuming a local, non clustered content install, you should be able to knock it out in a few hours.

Some factors that can extend the process:

- web tier installation
- slow x11 over VPN
- clustered
- networking issues
- not doing a proper pre-install checklist (e.g., not having credentials ready)

I've seen it take as long as a week for a non-expert to install.

Update if you have any specific questions.

-ryan